# Java calling JS with Rhino (Uint8Array is not defined)

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, call, rhino

I'm trying to use the Rhino lib to call some javascript from java code. But it seems that it is choking on a typed array. Here is my simple js file

```
function decrypt(version, iv, encryptedBuffer) {
    var output8;
    output8 = new Uint8Array(encryptedBuffer);
    var outputBuffer = output8.buffer;
    var output32 = new Int32Array(outputBuffer);
    ... more funny code
}
```

But when calling

```
jsFunction.call(rhino, scope, scope, params);
```

I get this

> sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError:
>   "Uint8Array" is not defined. (JavaScript#5680)

Is there something extra to configure to have my little js snippet run ?

Comment: Are you sure your version of Rhino supports typed arrays? *edit* I think they're only supported in Rhino 1.8 or later.

Comment: I'm using version 1.7.7.1 which in the change logs says typedArray supported. Do I need java 8 maybe? I'll try now

Comment: Well Java 8 ships with Nashorn, the new JavaScript runtime for the JVM. I just did a quick search and found [a bug on the topic](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/issues/151).

Comment: I'm doing this call from Android so I cannot use nashorn. Either way I just tried my original code running with java 1.8 I still get the same error
(To be clear I'm testing this on a normal Java (not from android) so that I'm 100% eveything is working before using it on Android)

Comment: How do you call JS code? Do you use rhino native classes or jdk API. Could you post your java code.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set setLanguageVersion(Context.VERSION_ES6)?
Typed Array is new Javascript feature.
Rhino does not allow Typed array call in old js versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use classes from package [`org.mozilla.javascript.typedarrays`](https://mozilla.github.io/rhino/javadoc/org/mozilla/javascript/typedarrays/package-summary.html):

```
importPackage(org.mozilla.javascript.typedarrays); 

var decrypt = function(version, iv, encryptedBuffer, off, len) {
    var output8 = new NativeUint8Array(encryptedBuffer,off,len);
    var outputBuffer = output8.buffer;
    var output32 = new NativeInt32Array(outputBuffer,off,len);
    //... more funny code
}

var encryptedBuffer = new NativeArrayBuffer(1024);
decrypt(null,null,encryptedBuffer,0,1024);
```