# Google Apps Script equivalent for JS typed arrays (Uint8Array and Uint16Array)

Tags: google-apps-script

When I try to run the following code in google apps script

```
  var numArray = [31, -117, 8, 8, -102, -124, 75, 88, 2, 0, 106, 117, 108, 121, 46, 116, 120, 116, 0, 1, 4, 0, -5, -1, 106, 117, 108, 121, -13, -113, 116, -57, 4, 0, 0, 0];
  var typedArray     = new Uint8Array(numArray);
```

...I get:

```
ReferenceError: "Uint8Array" is not defined.
```

At the same time

```
  var numArray = [31, -117, 8, 8, -102, -124, 75, 88, 2, 0, 106, 117, 108, 121, 46, 116, 120, 116, 0, 1, 4, 0, -5, -1, 106, 117, 108, 121, -13, -113, 116, -57, 4, 0, 0, 0];
  var typedArray     = new Array(numArray);
```

...works just fine. Is there a clever workaround way to implement a Uint8Array in google apps script?

Comment: What's the goal of using Uint8 bit arrays?  Is that just to save space on Googles server?  How big do you expect the array to be?

Comment: I am trying to use a js library (pulled into gas via eval()) and it expects a Uint8Array as an input. The array will be quite large.

Comment: GAS runs on Rhino, and probably not the latest version; [typed arrays are not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40219226).

Comment: I've had problems myself with signed/unsigned numeric arrays and have had to flop bytes.  The struggle is real.

Comment: @Xepoch, could I ask you to share your "byte flopping" code? Sounds like you were able to successfully imitate the functionality of a Uint8Array.

Comment: @July.Tech, http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/36220/25336

Comment: @Xepoch, this bit from the code snippet that you linked to effectively answers my question: `vegaArray[i]<0?vegaArray[i]+256:vegaArray[i];`. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so thanks to the comment from @Xepoch, here is the answer to my original question.

The equivalent to

```
  var numArray = [31, -117, 8, 8, -102, -124, 75, 88, 2, 0, 106, 117, 108, 121, 46, 116, 120, 116, 0, 1, 4, 0, -5, -1, 106, 117, 108, 121, -13, -113, 116, -57, 4, 0, 0, 0];
  var typedArray     = new Uint8Array(numArray);
```

is (in the absence of Uint8Array):

```
  var numArray = [31, -117, 8, 8, -102, -124, 75, 88, 2, 0, 106, 117, 108, 121, 46, 116, 120, 116, 0, 1, 4, 0, -5, -1, 106, 117, 108, 121, -13, -113, 116, -57, 4, 0, 0, 0];
  var typedArray = [];
  for(var i=0;i<numArray .length;i++) {
     typedArray.push(numArray [i]<0?numArray [i]+256:numArray [i]);
  }
```